# Typescript inference based on key value

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Let say we have some coords of different type:

```
const coords2d = {
  x: 1,
  y: 2
}

const coords3d = {
  x: 1,
  y: 2,
  z: 3
}
```

We have map for quick access:

```
const dimensionsMap = {
  keyFor2d: coords2d,
  keyFor3d: coords3d
}
```

Then we have function which gets value from map by key:

```
const getDimension = (key: keyof typeof dimensionsMap) => {
  return dimensionsMap[key]
}
```

Problem is when we execute function we get union type instead of specific:

```
const dimension = getDimension("keyFor3d")
// 
// Inspec dimension type:
/*
dimension: {
    x: number;
    y: number;
} | {
    x: number;
    y: number;
    z: number;
}
*/
```

and because of that we cannot access property of our specific dimension:

```
const zCoord = dimension.z
//
//Inspec error
/* 
Property 'z' does not exist on type '{ x: number; y: number; } | { x: number; y: number; z: number; }'.
  Property 'z' does not exist on type '{ x: number; y: number; }'
*/
```

Is there any way yo overcome it other than making type assertions like:

```
const zCoord = (dimension as typeof coords3d).z
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `getDimension` to the following:

```
const getDimension = <T extends keyof typeof dimensionsMap>(key: T) => {
  return dimensionsMap[key]
}
```